# Cannot use GUI on built-in screen but only on HDMI port

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg

I cannot use my internal monitor of my laptop for GUI desktop once Ubuntu starts up. When I had Ubuntu 20.4.1 LTS both the internal monitor as the external monitor worked and I could also use <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to extend my desktop. I now have Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. After the upgrade I had to reinstall the NVIDIA drivers.

I have an Intel integrated graphics chip and an NVIDIA GeForce 1050 Mobile GPU. I have installed the NVIDIA drivers (version 515.65.01) and I can use my second monitor which I can connect via HDMI (which is connected to the NVIDIA GPU card). Everything is working fine, except Ubuntu does not recognize the internal screen. When I switch to the Intel graphics chip using `sudo prime-select intel` and reboot I end up in the terminal and `startx` exits with an error.

If I start up my laptop without any HDMI connected it supposedly hangs on the filesystem checks. If I then connect a screen via HDMI I get my login screen on that monitor and the built-in screen turns black.

The problem might have started once I used the NVIDIA X Server GUI to change some settings, which changed the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

I have already tried deleting `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and then regenerating it with `sudo nvidia-xconfig`, but nothing is changed (except for the layout of the `xorg.conf` file).

### EDIT

The laptop screen works normal when I boot Windows (I have dualboot but only really use Ubuntu), so I think it must be some driver setting that I got wrong.

### EDIT 2

Added output of `xrandr --listproviders`. Furthermore, I realize that there is no entry named `PRIME Profiles` anymore in NVIDIA X Server Settings:
[image: Screenshot of NVIDIA X Server GUI]

### Debug Files and Outputs

**Current `xorg.conf`**

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 515.65.01

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

**Previous `xorg.conf` (also with the display problems)**:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 515.65.01

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Philips PHL 245E1"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 114.0
    VertRefresh     48.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +1920+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

**Output of lspci -k**

```
...

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
    DeviceName: Intel Kabylake HD Graphics GT2
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company HD Graphics 630
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

...

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
    DeviceName: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

...
```

xrandr only reports my external monitor:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+  74.97  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1440     59.91  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93
```

Output of `xrandr --listproviders`

```
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x1b7 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-0
```

Comment: In the end I just removed the Ubuntu installation and reinstalled it. I have my /home directory on a separate partition so it was a quick fix.